# Manually Trigger EJB Schedule for testing

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, schedule

I have a Method annotated with `javax.ejb.Schedule`:

```
@Schedule(minute = "00", hour = "23")
public void dailyTask()
```

It works perfectly, but for end-to-end testing purposes, I want to manually trigger this method, ideally without code changes.

I googled, searched for MBeans in JVisualVM but was not successful. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: you could inject this component into your testcase to call this public method manually, e.g. like this (untested):

```
@Singleton
public class YourClass {
    ...
    @Schedule(minute = "00", hour = "23")
    public void dailyTask() {
        ...
    }


public class YourTestClass {
    @EJB
    private YourClass yourTestClass;
    ...
    void someTestMethod() {
        yourTestClass.dailyTask();
    }
```